# Checking value of an attribute against value of other attributes in input json data

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am accepting information about database table schema. It contains information about table columns. Thus, as evident, those columns have `name` attribute of type `string`. However those names need not be from pre-selected names list. They can be anything input by user. Now I also want to accept the unique key for the table which can be a composite key and contain only those columns that are input by the user. In other words, the unique key can be comprised of the columns that are provided by the user in json data.

Thus technically what I need is : dynamically populated string enumeration (from input json data) which will be a type for items of array representing unique key. Thus each element of the array will be a column name.

For example below json data

```
"columns": 
{
    "col1": "val1",
    "col2": "val2",
    "col3": "val3"
},
"uniquelKey": ["val1","val2"]
```

is valid, but

```
"columns": 
{
    "col1": "val1",
    "col2": "val2",
    "col3": "val3"
},
"uniquelKey": ["val1","val4"]
```

is not valid since `val4` specified in `uniqueKey` is not present in the `columns` list.
Is this achievable with current json-schema specification and implementations? I didnt found any direction in this regard.

My current json schema looks like this:

```
...
"attributes":
{
    "type": "array",
    "items":
    {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": 
        {
            "name": {"type": "string"},
            ...
        },
        "required": ["name",...],
        ...
    }
},
"uniqueKey": 
{
    ... ** here is where I have stuck ** ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this can not be done with the current version of JSON Schema.  There is no mechanism for referencing the values in the data that is being validated.  Similarly, there is no way to validate an object where with properties `startDate` and `endDate` where `startDate` is less than `endDate`.

There is a proposal to address this limitation that is being considered for a future JSON Schema draft.  So, you might be able to do this in the future, but not right now.

See the JSON Schema spec discussion at [issue 51: *type enhancement: `$data`*](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/51).