# OpenAPIV3 conditional validation between properties?

Tags: validation, swagger, openapi

Problem: Need to add validation to only allow `min < max`. Can this be done using OpenAPIV3 schema validation? Appreciate your help, could not figure this out reading the documentation.

Range can be provided using `minimum` and `maximum`, but how do i refer the value of an existing property?

```
openAPIV3Schema:
  type: object
  required:
  - min
  - max
  properties:
    min:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    max: 
      type: integer
      format: int32
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: It is not possible with atleast the current version(v3.0.3).

Explanation:

Since minimum and maximum properties in the [OpenAPI Specification](https://swagger.io/specification/) are taken from [JSON Schema Validation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-wright-json-schema-validation-00), you can refer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347095/checking-value-of-an-attribute-against-value-of-other-attributes-in-input-json-d) where it is mentioned that this is currently not possible.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31080177/783964) also mentions that there was [a proposal](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/51) that introduces `$data` but that also seems to be rejected now. As a side note, even though there is no official support for `$data`, some non-standard JSON Schema validator implementations like [AJV](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv#data-reference) have support for `$data`.